# How do I make DOSBox show in full screen mode?

Tags: dosbox

I have enable FullScreenmode in Dosbox under Ubuntu 12.04 . But still i am not getting it in Fullscreen. My turbo c++ windows is less than my screen size.

Answer (score 46):

First, press `ctrl + F10` to lock mouse to dosbox and then try `alt + Enter`.

Comment: works on mac too

Answer (score 19):

****You need to edit *dosbox-0.74.conf* as given below****

Go to terminal and type **`gedit /home/<USER_NAME>/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf`**

and make these changes:

```
fullscreen=true
fulldouble=true
fullresolution=1366x768
windowresolution=1366x768
output=opengl  #**MOST IMPORTANT** 
autolock=true
```

Now save the file and open dosbox. It should be fullscreen with full workspace.

**NOTE :** Original source of this answer : [**Click Here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/731673/497359)

Answer (score 5):

- Goto /home/**user**/dosbox.conf
- Find resolution
- Change fullresolution from original to your choice (eg.
  fullresolution=640x480)
- Leave windowresolution intact (i.e, windowresolution=original) as you
  might want a smaller sized window.

**Optional**:
change fullscreen to true (i.e, fullscreen=true) if you want to start dosbox in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 4):

I think the Alt-Enter command makes DOSBox go full-screen. That might not be your problem, though.

Comment: This is the right answer for my problem (which was escaping full screen after alt tab)

Comment: this is defiantly the right answer. Also see here:  https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=35255

Comment: Note to Linux: this might need _**Right** Alt_ (sometimes referred as _"Alt Gr"_)

Answer (score 1):

```
fullresolution=auto
windowresolution=auto
```

for me auto setting on these two functions, works better.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is for accessing mouse

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is to switch from full screen to small.

Answer (score 0):

Severus Tux solution worked on my raspberry pi, but took up far too much computing power. Extreme lag and overheating followed from just rendering the dos prompt.

Another solution is to change the "scaler" parameter to a size that fits your screen the best. you can either double, or tripple the number of pixels used:

```
scaler=normal2x forced
```

or

```
scaler=normal3x forced
```

pick the one that fits your fullscreen mode the best.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Dosbox conf files inside ScummVM files, it uses:

```
output=overlay
```

(Also a youtuber recommended)

```
fullresolution=0x0x
```

Also for RetroPie DosBox, it had the settings here:

```
~/.dosbox/dosbox-SVN.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's mention that all configuration info is available here https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf

Regarding your question:

**1. Where is the config file on Linux ?**

> For Linux the configfile is created on the first run in ~/.dosbox/ The
> name is dosbox-{version}.conf where version is currently 0.74

-> Your config file is here: /home/<USER_NAME>/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf

**2. What are the full-screen related settings in this config file ?**

```
fullscreen = true | false
fulldouble = true | flase
```

-> edit /home/<USER_NAME>/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf

and set:

```
fullscreen = true
fulldouble = true
```

**3. Bonus**

Changing full-screen mode **at runtime** (as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175763/how-do-i-make-dosbox-show-in-full-screen-mode/731847#886624) )

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to lock/unlock mouse in DOSBOX window (if needed)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle DOSBOX's full-screen mode