# Can't get fullscreen dosbox on ubuntu

Tags: dosbox

I installed DosBox on my Ubuntu 14.04.3:

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

I edited the `/home/severus/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf` from:

```
fullscreen=false
fulldouble=false
fullresolution=original
```

to (as mine is 1366x768):

```
fullscreen=true
fulldouble=true
fullresolution=1366x768
```

Now when I open DoxBox, Yes it becomes full screen but the **usable area** still remains the same:

Only This much :

[image]

How can I make it **Fullscreen**?? as it can be done on windows, with all fonts bigger and with **larger working space**

NOTE: for reference , [here is the `dosbox-0.74.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15007472/) file.

Comment: 1 more **NOTE :** I have nvidia-352 graphics driver installed, Is something related to it???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fullscreen=false 
fulldouble=true 
fullresolution=1366x768 
windowresolution=1366x768 
output=opengl
```

This config worked pretty well for me. It creates a window the size of your desktop display (which is almost fullscreen-it leaves just the top status bar) and you can always just enter fullscreen after that with 
    alt + enter

Comment: :( I tried it, but its still same :(

Comment: Try setting "fulldouble=false" as well?

Comment: :'( still its same...

Comment: Maybe this helps then:                                                                  `fullscreen=false
fulldouble=true
fullresolution=1366x768
windowresolution=1366x768
output=opengl `                                              This config worked pretty well for me. It creates a window the size of your desktop display (which is almost fullscreen-it leaves just the top status bar) and you can always just enter fullscreen after that with `alt + enter`.

Comment: Man! you did it :-D Thanks a lot,  I kept 
`fullscreen=true`  `fulldouble=true` `fullresolution=1366x768`   `windowresolution=1366x768` **`output=opengl`** `autolock=true`  **opengl** was the culprit :-P   as you said.  Now please modify your answer and include all this so that it helps everybody with similar problems and Even I can accept it.  Once again, thanks :-)

Comment: @m1xalis You might want to edit that into your answer

Comment: @SeverusTux Glad that worked out for you. Dosbox is a gem of a program imo.